# Laravel 6 validate multiple columns

Tags: laravel

Using the following code to create and update records with Laravel 6, how to add a unique validation that combines 'iso' and 'division' columns must unique, for both update and create? Also how to update the 'updated_at' column automatically without 'touch' it?

```
 public function upsert(Request $request)
    {
        $this->authorize('manage','App\Admin\Division');
        $this->validate($request,[
                'records.iso' => 'required|regex:/^[A-Z]{2}$/',
                'records.division' => 'required|min:2|max:3',
                'records.remarks' => 'min:2|max:255|string|nullable',
        ],
           [ 'records.iso.required'=>'Country iso Requied',
             'records.iso.regex'=>'Country iso format : AA',
             'records.division.required'=>'Division Code must entered',
             'records.division.min'=>'Division Code minimum 2 characters',
             'records.division.max'=>'Division Code maximum 3 characters',
            ],
        );
        $validatedData = $request->records;
        if($validatedData['id']){   // have id, old record -> update       
            Division::where('id', $validatedData['id'])->update($validatedData);
            //*******/ To correct updated_at no auto updated
            $results = Division::find($validatedData['id']);
            $results->touch();
            //****** */ End of correction
        }else{ // no id -> create record
            $validatedData['auth'] = Auth::id();
            $results = Division::create($validatedData);
        }
        return  ['divisions' => $results];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All the validation rules apply for each field, i think you can do a `foreach` to workaround and compact the code, something like:

```
foreach ($records  as $key => $record) {
  $fields['record'.$key] = 'iso', 'division';
  $rules['record'.$key] = 'required|min:2';
}
  $validator = Validator::make($fields, $rules);
```

In the rules array you can put all the shared rules, but you have to create the other complex validation rules after this, so i think that your validation now is just fine.

And with the `updated_at` field, use the `updateOrCreate`

```
$results = Division::updateOrCreate(
   ['id', $validatedData['id'],
   [$validatedData]
);
```

Adapt the above example for your code.